# Wp-Admin FTPS Connection Error unlike Filezilla

Tags: admin, wp-admin, errors, permissions, ftp

My wordpress [website](http://sonergonul.net/) is just moved FTP to FTPS protocol.

When I tried to make a connection with [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), the connection is successful. There is nothing wrong with my FTPS connection.

[image]

```
Status: Connecting to 88.247.100.147:16666...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "sonergonul@88.247.100.147" 16666
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Yes
Command:    Pass: **************
Status: Connected to 88.247.100.147
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/home/sonergonul"
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /home/sonergonul
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Command:    mtime "sonergonul_net"
Response:   1326036705
Status: Timezone offsets: Server: 7200 seconds. Local: 10800 seconds. Difference: 3600 seconds.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

But in my [wp-admin](http://sonergonul.net/wp-admin), when I tried to [update](http://sonergonul.net/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-upgrade) my wordpress version auto, these informations are not accepted.

[image]

Error code means:

> There was a problem connecting to the server, please check the
>   connection settings.

My all files under the `88.247.100.147:16666/home/sonergonul/sonergonul_net`. All tried to connect all the possibilities in my Server name (88.247.100.147, 88.247.100.147:16666, sonergonul.net) but no one was accepted. I think I miss some point but couldn't find it.

Doesn anyone have an idea for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FileZilla you use **SFTP** connection to access your server and it works (because it was setup on server). But in wp-admin you use **FTPS** connection, which is probably doesn't setup on server. Pay attention that SFTP != FTPS.

A solution could be to change File System method in your `wp-config.php` file by adding `FS_METHOD` constant with `direct` value, it will change upgrade method from ftp to direct:

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Another solution could be correct configuration of your hosting server to allow you FTPS connections.

And finally check file permissions of `wp-content` folder. It should be writable for user, by which you run your site.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. Adding define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' ); is perfectly works!